# style="display: none" attribute not working in JTextPane

Tags: java, attributes, styles, jtextpane

I am working on creating an html editor in java using JTextPane. The attribute style = "display: none" doesn't seem to be working here as expected. Help me out here.
My code is:

```
JTextPane basePane = new JTextPane(); 
basePane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
basePane.setContentType("text/html");
basePane.setText("<html><body><p style=\"display: none\" >hello world!</p></body></html>");
```

the string "hello world!" is still being printed. 
I tried using the div tags and placed the style="display: none" attribute there. it does not work there too.
Help me out here!

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: try Visibility: hidden insted of display: none

Comment: @S-Wing: What would that accomplish? What reason would there be that that would work instead of `display: none`? And of course, `visibility: hidden` would leave blank space in the layout where the paragraph would be (unlike `display: none`).

Comment: @S-Wing in my code there is a use-case where I am displaying an HTML page from an external source, where I cant modify the HTML page. Making the style property work would be a more permanent solution. Is this a bug in Java or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to create your own view if you want to implement this. The support for CSS in JTextPane is very partial.

Try something like this:

```
    //Create a view that inherites from InlineView and behave the way you want.
    //In your case, it should react to getAttributes().getAttribute(CSS.Attribute.DISPLAY);
    private class HideableView extends InlineView {
        public HideableView(Element elem) { super(elem); }
        //Implement your expected behaviour here
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, Shape a){}
    }


    //Create a View Factory that will replace InlineViews by your custom View
    public static class HTMLBetterFactory extends HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory {
        @Override
        public View create(Element elem) {
            AttributeSet attrs = elem.getAttributes();
            Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
            Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
            if (o == HTML.Tag.CONTENT) {
                if(attrs.getAttribute(CSS.Attribute.DISPLAY).toString().equals("none"))
                      return new HideableView(elem);
            }
            return super.create(elem);
        }
    }


//Create an HTMLEditorKit that will use your custom Factory
public class HTMLBetterEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {

    private final HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory factory = new HTMLBetterFactory();
        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return factory;
        }
    }
}

//Import your HTMLEditorKit into your JTextPane
HTMLBetterEditorKit editorKit = new HTMLBetterEditorKit();
myJTextPane.setEditorKit(editorKit);
```

This is for inline elements, but you can reproduce the process for other elements.

Comment: How do I make the HideableView, not visible? I want the element to be present in the Document but hidden when rendering it. I went through the Java Documentation of View and all its sub-classes, there is no method available to hide it. I am pretty new to HTML parsing in Java. What am I missing here?

Comment: The view works almost like a SwingComponent. You can hide it by overriding the `isVisible`method for instance.

Comment: the `isVisible` method only returns if the view is visible or not. It does not modify the visibility of the View, which is by default visible. I tried overriding the `isVisible` method and added a few print statements in it. Nothing was printed. the function was never called.

Comment: `getAttributes().getAttribute(CSS.Attribute.DISPLAY)` returns `none`, if the display attribute is set to none.

Comment: Are you sure that your HideableView is successfully created instead of regular InlineView ? Another approach would be to Override the `print` method and the `getMin/Max/PreferredSpan` methods to just display nothing

Comment: Yes, HideableView was successfully created, only for that particular element. Right now I'm having a workaround by removing that particular element from the document and displaying it. It works. But it is not a proper solution.

Comment: I tried overriding the `getMin/Max/PreferredSpan` and returning `0.0f` for all the functions. The element still got displayed. Can anyone tell me about how an element is put on a view and rendered? I guess that might help solve the problem

Comment: Did you also override the paint method?

Comment: I tried overriding the `paint` method now, and it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wrote `print` earlier instead of `paint`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was slightly different but may be still relevant to others who end up here. I was rendering some HTML in a JLabel and wanted to hide some elements conditionally. I did not need any dynamic visibility, so I ended up pre-filtering in Java to just prevent the elements I want hidden from even making it to the HTML source.